# How to installing PHP71 on RHEL 7 that requires HTTPD24 with HTTPD

Tags: installation, httpd, rhel7, php7

We have a RHEL 7 server that is offline <s>and only connected to RedHat repo via a satelite.</s>

When i try to manual install the PHP71 from the `rpm` files, it hits an error that say `Requires HTTPD24_HTTPD`

The server already have the `HTTPD` package from the main repo installed.

Anyway to tell yum to look at the `HTTPD` service instead of the `HTTPD24`? Or is there any other way to proceed with this?

**UPDATE**:
Further check with the admin, it is mentioned that there's no satellite repo, and the `yum` repo are iso files mounted to the server (It's a VM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package you are looking for is provided by Red Hat Software Collections, which needs to be enabled on your system.

On a system receiving packages directly from Red Hat, this repo is:

```
[root@llothien ~]# subscription-manager repos | grep -A3 rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
Repo ID:   rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Software Collections RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/$releasever/$basearch/rhscl/1/os
Enabled:   1
```

Since you're on Satellite, the Satellite system must provide a channel corresponding to this Red Hat repo. Contact the person responsible for Satellite in your organization for further information.

Comment: Thanks. I had double checked, and the admin told me the repo are iso images mounted to the server (It's a VM). Hence there's no satellite involved. I'll update my question..

Comment: @ipohfly Your admin still needs to provide these packages, perhaps in another ISO image.

Comment: Anyway that i can work this out without involving other party? Since HTTPD already installed, can i just ignore the dependency error and proceed with the php installation?

Comment: You need to be having this conversation with your admin, not with us. We can't help you get the required packages to your offline system.

Comment: End up downloaded all the RPMs one by one and install via yum. Thanks.